# Can we tag a location in No man's sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Yeah, tagging a location so we won't get confused while flying within atmosphere of any planet. Unlike other open world games; NMS has no map (obviously, It's a procedural generated world). Still we find places like Monolith, Colonial outpost,  Transmission, Shelter. Once, we find multiple places, can we tag them? for better understanding? It's always confusing to remember while flying which place is visited and which is not. I often visit same place by mistake. haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in the traditional sense, like in MGSV, but [Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/no-mans-sky/2016/8/22/12585546/tag-buildings-analysis-visor) says

> Using your Analysis Visor, you can scan buildings and structures. Doing this will put a white dot above them on your screen and make them show up as a waypoint both on your minimap and on your HUD.
>
> This tagging process isn't permanently visible. Your tag seems to have a range of about six or seven minutes worth of walking distance, so it's a good temporary solution to help you with a limited task, but don't rely on it for a cross-continental journey. Once you're back in range, the tagged building will show up again, though.

I'm afraid this is the closest thing.

Comment: It bugs out, I've placed 1 point on a tradepost went to scout something. Then on flying back the waypoint was pointing to a whole different location, somewhere I haven't been too yet.

Comment: That "tagging" definitely is terrible. When you scan, you accidentally tag anything you see in the scanner. Even stuff miles away gets tagged, stuff I have not visited before. Also, the markers get lost when you save/load a game.

Comment: Its pretty bad. Agreed. Kind of another oversight in the game. Probably due to time pressures from Sony Is my guess

Comment: I think I read somewhere that a revamp of the current mapping system is in the works, so there may be still be hope.

Answer (score 0):

Icons represent the waypoints that you have discovered. They float around your HUD. They seems to be the same but they are not. For exaxmple, you discovered a normal waypoint only for saving, and a waypoint that is for saving and trading. The icons are the same, but if you are standing faraway or driving your starship, the one with the word 'Terminal' under the time taken to reach destination is the waypoint with trade market, whereas the icon that only has the time is just a normal waypoint where you can only save the game. Just notice the words under the time. 'Depot' is where you get a lot of resource supply, but currently in my planet, I can only find a lot platinum in those depots. 'Drop Pot' is where you have...the drop pot for upgrading your exosuit; However most of the time, if you have used that drop pot, the icons will still show up. Google more about this to understand all the tag.